# Have ion-input only accept 20 digit numbers?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I've tried using

```
<ion-input formControlName="LPNumber" type="number">

LPNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20), Validators.maxLength(20)]]
```

but that doesn't seem to validate.... in chrome at least. Is there a better way to validate a 20 digit number in Ionic 4?

Comment: try `<ion-input formControlName="LPNumber" type="number"  maxlength="20">`

Comment: I was able to get maxlength and minlength = 20 to work if I switched the input type to 'tel'. But when it's number those validators no longer work correctly

Answer (score 0):

So by design if your input type is "number" the maxLength will be ignored.

There are many ways to workaround this. I used this approach (hacky a bit):

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>MaxLength 4</ion-label>
  <ion-input onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==4) return false;"
    type="number"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ion-input formControlName="LPNumber" minlength="20" maxlength="20" type="number">
```

Answer (score 0):

My way to do this is by:

```
<ion-input type="number" (ionChange)="onNumberChange($event)"></ion-input>

...
onNumberChange($event) {
    // checks of number only. Doesn't allow + - . for in input
    $event.target.value = $event.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
    // checks for maxlength doesn't allow greater than specified length
    $event.target.value = $event.target.value.length > 20 ? $event.target.value.substring(0, 20) : $event.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give `type="text"` then allow, but you give `type="number"` then not allow Validation, so you can give below like

**page.html**

```
<ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-label position="stacked">Input Number</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="LPNumber" type="tel"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item no-padding lines="none" class="validator-error"
      *ngIf="property_form_step3.controls.LPNumber.hasError('required') && property_form_step3.controls.LPNumber.touched">
      <p class="content">Please Enter Required Field!</p>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item no-padding lines="none" class="validator-error"
      *ngIf="property_form_step3.controls.LPNumber.hasError('maxlength') && property_form_step3.controls.LPNumber.touched">
      <p class="content">Allow Only 20 Digits Number!</p>
    </ion-item>
```

**page.ts**

```
LPNumber: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.required])],
```

**page.scss**

```
.validator-error{
    --background: transparent;
    color: #d44848;
    --min-height: 30px;

    .content{
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```